# React Native: Bracekts warns,Error indexing files - while opening a newly created project

Tags: react-native, adobe-brackets

Opened newly created react native app and Brackets showed this error.Atom showed it is up to date. Other people using brackets for this development.

Error indexing files.

contains more than 30,000 files, features that work across multiple files may be disabled or behave as if the project was empty.

Reason+suggestion?